# Emacs: bind smth to right Alt key

Tags: emacs

I want to bind Right-<kbd>Alt</kbd> key to toggle-input-method function and Left-<kbd>Alt</kbd> to <kbd>Meta</kbd>. 
But Emacs identify both <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys as <kbd>Meta</kbd>. 
How can I get Emacs to distinguish between the <kbd>Alt</kbd> buttons?

os: Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using GNOME, you can check what is your Alt key behavior in `System` -> `Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Layout` tab -> `Option` button -> `Alt\Win key behavior` and make some tests if there is an option satisfying you.

Also quite much depends on keyboard layout you are using - you can look at [xkeycaps](http://www.jwz.org/xkeycaps/) - GUI for xmodmap, which controls key mappings in X - and check if Left / Right `Alt` is assigned to `Meta`.